# Death by tooltip - stylecop/resharper/intellisense - how to I get intellisense tooltips to show?

Tags: resharper, intellisense, stylecop

Annoying crap.  I am using VS 2012; I have ReSharper and StyleCop (SC) installed.  If a StyleCop warning is enabled on a line of code, I can't get rid of it unless I fix it.  I want to handle the SC warning later and see the intellisense tooltip on one of the class references defined.  How the hell do I do this?  I do NOT want to temporily disable SC, I only want to tell it to "shut up" for a second so I can view intellisense.

Comment: You say you don't want to disable StyleCop, but what about temporay rule suppression using the [`SuppressMessage` attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2009/08/10/rule-suppressions.aspx)? It's ugly, overkill for what you need, and you have to remember to remove it afterwards, but it should work.

Comment: As I said, it's ugly : ) Pascal's solution is clearly much better, though I suspect the exact key combination will prove easy to forget. Luckily, we have search for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Resharper you can quickly disable the analysis of the current file (including the StyleCop analysis) with the following keyboard shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

Check the intellisense tooltip and after that re-activate the analysis again using the same shortcut.

Comment: Ty. I guess that's the answer; would think that like holding shift or something and hovering would be more helpful, oh well, feature request.

Comment: Unfortunately, Resharper handles all addins generating static analysis errors the same way as Resharper's own analysis rules.  Only StyleCop can be very verbose on legacy code files.